# 'expected primary expression before ')' error'

Tags: c++, windows

I am making a game engine and I keep getting an error whenever I compile the project.  The compiler spits out this error:

> expected primary expression before ')' token.

Can anyone help me with this?  I will provide the line with the error below.

```
if (GameInitialize(HINSTANCE))
```

Comment: Somebody asked you what color you what your game to be, but instead of saying "red" or "blue" you said "color".

Answer (score 6):

You need to pass a *value* as the parameter when you call the function. At least in Windows, `HINSTANCE` is defined as a type (and I doubt anything but Windows uses that name).

Typical use would be in `WinMain`, which receives the `HINSTANCE` of the current process as a parameter:

```
int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

    // ...
    if (GameInitialize(hInstance))
        // whatever
}
```

Note that C++ (like C) is case sensitive, so `hInstance` and `HINSTANCE` aren't the same, even though they're equal in a case-insensitive comparison. This is often problematic for people who've used languages (e.g., Pascal) that are normally case-insensitive.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm new to C++. How exactly would I pass the value as a parameter to the function if its an if statement?